# Words that get copied are not the same as shown in websites

Tags: html, web, copy-paste

I recently copied a word from a website and pasted in a document. It is shown below:

```
name@example.org
```

But when I copied and pasted in google docs, I got it as `name@example.ca.us`

After getting confused, I looked at its html. It is represented as,

```
<a href="mailto:name@example.ca.us">name@example.org</a>
```

What content will actually be copied from a website when we copy? Isn't the actual word what we see get copied?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)

Comment: And it depends on web browser, not html itself.

Comment: "It's because your doing it the wrong way!" - this is just a joke. Actually this is how browsers have been working since I can remember. You just need to paste to none formatted text editor like notepad then copy again, from there you won't have the html thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it will only copy the text that you see but because its a link, `<a href>` it copies the info in the html too.

Same way that if you copied a link and pasted it into word it would still be a link in word, not just the text. The way I avoid it is by pasting into notepad first then copying it again.

I wouldn't worry too much about it.